# When i select Date in SharePoint Dateimecontrol Defaulty 9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM?

Tags: sharepoint-server, datetimecontrol

In my page i was using SharePoint Dateimecontrol.But by default it will come date and time .I gave dateonly = true.

```
  <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="DateTimeControl1" runat="server"  Visible="false"  DateOnly="true"  
                                                                 CssClassTextBox="field_date_contractdetails" />
```

[image]
when i was select the date it was coming like 9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM.How can i fix this issue.I want to display only Date.

```
dtEndDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
                            string Datesplit =Convert.ToString(NewValue.Replace(NewValue.Split(',').Last() + ",", "").Trim());
                            var Dateval = Datesplit.Split(',')[1];
                            dtEndDate.DateOnly = true;
                            dtEndDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Dateval);
```

i was used ToShortDateString();But also it was coming with date and time.

Here NewValue contains Some value with Date Like (some,9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM)

Comment: Does this DateTimeControl correspond to a library column of date/time type?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
void filterDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var target = Convert.ToString((filterDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()));
        string camlQuery = "<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name ='Due Date' />" + "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + target + " </Value></Leq></Where>";
        query.Query = camlQuery;
        MyCustomView.Query = query;

    }
```